# Dataframe behaving differently after concat

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The below code is not working properly after merging two dataframes using `concat`.
Before merging the code is working fine:

```
hours_cm02 = 0
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.loc[i,'Team_name'] == "CM02":
        hours_cm02 = hours_cm02+df.loc[i,'Actual Billed Hours']
print(hours_cm02)
```

I am getting below error:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I used below code to merge

```
frames = [df1,df2]
df = pd.concat(frames)
```

The structure (no of column and names of columns) is same for both data frame

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that after you perform concatenate you have duplicate values in the index of your new dataframe. The line of code `df.loc[i,'Team_name']` can then refer to more than one row in your dataframe.

Solutions:

1. Change `df = pd.concat(frames)` to `df = pd.concat(frames, ignore_index=True)`. This should reset the index after you concatenate making the index unique.
2. Change the code to use iloc which refers to the row number rather than the index. i.e. use `df.iloc[i]['Team_name']` and `df.iloc[i]['Actual Billed Hours']`